# Load Fragments AFTER Permission Check in Parent Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, runtime-permissions

I have an activity with three fragments, first is the map fragment, and the other two are recyclerview fragments. I tried asking for permission in the maps fragment directly, but it had a bunch of issues, which I fixed by adding permission check in the parent activity instead of maps fragment. 
Right now if permission is allowed it goes to my location and zooms in, and if it is not it goes to the custom location. But the first time I install the app it loads the fragments as soon as I start it, and after that I am asked for my permission.

It works, but what ***I want is to load my fragments only after the permissions were accepted or declined*** by the user, the first time I install and start my app.

My main activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    tutorialUsed = false;
    tutorialPage = 1;

    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params =
            (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
    params.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL
            | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS);

    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
    // session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{ android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {

        List<Restaurant> Restaurants = new ArrayList<>();

        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_one)));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_two)));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_three)));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);

        final ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        View headView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

        String name = user.get("name");

        FloatingActionButton selectDate = findViewById(R.id.fabSelectDate);
        selectDate.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            DialogFragment picker = new DatePickerFragment();
            picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
        });

        TextView myUserName = headView.findViewById(R.id.idUsername);
        myUserName.setText(name);

        ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL; // or use DEFAULT
        // generate color based on a key (same key returns the same color), useful for list/grid views
        int color = generator.getColor(user.get("uid"));
        String firstLetter = name.substring(0, 1);
        TextDrawable textDrawable = TextDrawable.builder().buildRound(firstLetter, color);

        ImageView imageView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.profile_image_nav);
        String myImage = user.get("image");
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(AppConfig.URL_PROFILE_PHOTO + myImage)
                .placeholder(textDrawable)
                .error(textDrawable)
                .transform(new CircleTransform())
                .centerCrop()
                .fit()
                .into(imageView);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent accountIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(accountIntent);
        });
        myUserName.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent accountIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(accountIntent);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `PermissionCheck` when you are creating your `MapFragment`. So it ask first for `permissions` then simply if permissions aceepted start `MapFragment`, and if denied it do nothing.

Comment: @Heisen-Berg I tried adding it in my maps fragment already but had a bunch of issues, and the answer I found was to move it to parent activity

Comment: what kind of issues you are facing in mapfragment ?

Comment: @Tej [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47855319/adding-default-location-if-user-doesnt-allow-permission-for-a-fine-location-for) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47885296/on-map-fine-location-permission-denied-go-to-custom-location). And the best answer I found was that it is an android bug, and the solution is to move it to parent activity.

Comment: im not sure about this idea but you can try  . in your mapfragment . before setContentView .ask a permission if user accept set than  your xml and do  as usual otherwise  ask permission again

Comment: @Tej I will try that today and let you know if it works

Comment: i'm not saying that this is a proper approach but for your problem this may be work around for you..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162413/discussion-between-kemo-and-tej).

Comment: @Tej Tried this but couldn't make it work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, so maybe someone else will be able to use this.

In my fragment I created a refresh method, called restaurant markers again:

```
public void ReloadMarkerFragment() {
    mMap.clear();

    if (!latitudeSetting.equals("") && !longitudeSetting.equals("")) {
        latitude = Double.parseDouble(latitudeSetting);
        longitude = Double.parseDouble(longitudeSetting);
    }

    setMarker(latitude, longitude, "", userName, "");

    fetchAllrestaurants(userId);
}
```

And in my main acitvity I referenced that fragment method:

```
private void CallChildFragmentMethods(ViewPager viewPager, PagerAdapter adapter) {
    MapsFragment mapsFragment = (MapsFragment) adapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, 0);
    mapsFragment.ReloadMapsFragment();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {

        case MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // phone permission is granted, call register and pass empty getMyPhoneNumber
               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                CallChildFragmentMethods(viewPager, adapter);
            } else {
                // phone permission is not granted, call register and pass empty phone string
               //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                CallChildFragmentMethods(viewPager, adapter);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

So for either result I get a reload of my maps fragment.

Hope it helps someone.